# How to solve or suppress wall of warnings using any pystan code

Tags: cython, pystan

When I run any pystan code, the output is what I expect, but I get a wall of warnings.

I've tried updating pystan and cython, as these are mentioned in the wall of warnings. My pystan is now version 2.17.1 and cython 0.29.2. I'm running python3.7.

```
import pystan
model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)  # this will take a minute
y = model.sampling(n_jobs=1).extract()['y']
y.mean()  # should be close to 0
```

The error message that I get starts with:

```
/home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /tmp/tmp8_plkepg/stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_5335140894361802645.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1823:0,
                 from /home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmp8_plkepg/stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_5335140894361802645.cpp:688:
/home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.66.0/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp:19:0,
                 from /home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.66.0/boost/numeric/odeint/util/ublas_wrapper.hpp:24,
                 from /home/femke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Is this something to worry about? If not, how do I specifically disable these warnings, but not from other parts of my code? If so, what should I change.

**Edit**: after having read the question [Cython Numpy warning about NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API when using MemoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789055/cython-numpy-warning-about-npy-no-deprecated-api-when-using-memoryview), I still don't know how to safely disable this warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython Numpy warning about NPY\_NO\_DEPRECATED\_API when using MemoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789055/cython-numpy-warning-about-npy-no-deprecated-api-when-using-memoryview)

Comment: It isn't something you should worry about. The duplicate I suggested doesn't have any (useful) information about how to disable it (so may only be half useful)

Comment: Wait for Cython3.0: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2498

Comment: Thanks. That is unfortunate, as the wall makes it impossible to see print statement that come before in my spyder IPython console. Hope they fix it soon!

Comment: I think in the short term if you can define `NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API` to be `NPY_1_7_API_VERSION-1` it should work. I don't know how to do that from pystan though.

Comment: Don't know that either.. What kind of file should I be looking for to change that in?

Comment: There looks to be an undocumented `extra_compile_args` option for `StanModel`. Try passing `extra_compile_args=['-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=6']` or something similar. I have real way of testing this though

Comment: Unfortunately, the wall of warnings doesn't change if I do that :(. I wouldn't know what something similar is here.